# Set App Service Connection strings from Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have a `.Net Framework 4.6.2` Web Application which deployed in `Azure App Service`. In `Web.config` file, it has some passwords in `<appSettings>` element, and some connection strings in `<connectionStrings>` element. I want to keep both in `Azure Key Vault` secrets, and retrieve them from `Azure DevOps` with service connection and push the secrets' value to `Application settings` and `Connection strings` in `App Service`.
[image]

I'm able to do this for `Application settings` in `Deploy Azure App Service > Application and Configuration Settings > App settings`, but not for `Connection strings`. How to set App Service Connection strings from Azure DevOps? Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "Azure App Service Settings" to set the connection string. Hope this helps!

[image: Azure App Service Settings]

You can refer to this [official issue thread](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9017#issuecomment-556936128)
Let me know if it worked.

Comment: At first, I got error message `SyntaxError:***Unexpected***token***p***in***JSON***at***position***1`, then I realised that they use new JSON format for these Connection Strings and App Settings. I change them to JSON, bingo! It works. I love this new PREVIEW function. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help :)