# How do you an set an Azure App Service Connection String with DevOps release pipeline

Tags: azure, devops

When you look at the Configuration of an App Service there is a section for Connection Strings [Connection String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UnhG.png)

Any idea how I would set that in a release pipeline.  I have tried using both app settings and configuration settings with no luck

[Config Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcinX.png)

Comment: https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/azure-app-service-settings-from-azure-devops/

Comment: This answer is already answered - [Use "Azure App Service Settings"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60702753/12073016)